# how can display Activity Indicator up to image is loaded into ImageView?

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to download 5MB `Image` from Server for this I want to display `UIActivityIndicatorView` still Image completely downloaded and display on `UIImageView`,
so how can display `Activity Indicator` up to image is loaded into `ImageView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MonoTouch.Dialog uses a `UIActivityIndicatorView` when loading new web pages into an `UIWebView`. It's fairly easy to use, see the corresponding source code [here](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs#L591).

Answer (score 1):

Use [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) .It is the better way to load images asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Place an Activity Indicator (via Interface Builder or manually) on your view. Set the property to "hide when not animating".

When doing server call, call [activityIndicator startAnimating] (IBOutlet property). When returning with actual image, call [activityIndicator stopAnimating]. When stopping, it wil automatically hide.

You can also use the activity indicator in the iPhon/Pad status bar. To do this, use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES]; Set to NO for hiding it ... (obviously)

Take a look at http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-uiimage-asynchronously/ for a sample of dl'ing an image. You would stop the activity indicator in the didReceiveData function.